# Yocto: oe_runmake failed, error in do_configure from bitbake image

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm building yocto image. I'm having an error when I type bitbake piflo command (piflo is my image name) like shown figure below:

[image]

oe_runmake failed with do_configure and No rule for 'clean'

> | make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.

So I tried to make empty function 'do_clean' at "/opt/sanghun/meta-piflo/recipes-devtools/python/python-dateutil_1.5.bb" like shown figure below:

[image]

> do_clean(){ }

but it doesn't work...

Does anybody have an idea for this? Please help me out here.

If needs more information or code, I will EDIT.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `make clean` step in `do_configure` by default. Apparently the Makefile you are using misses that target. Just do this definition in your recipe:

```
CLEANBROKEN = "1"
```

This will skip the `make clean` step.

Links to the documentation:

- about `do_configure`: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-tasks-configure
- `CLEANBROKEN` variable: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-CLEANBROKEN

BTW you can remove your empty `do_clean` - it is unrelated to the error you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you for your help!